# MATLAB logicical indexing RAM constraints; workaround?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, indexing

I have an array  `I = 6100x6300x72` which is applied to function, and the result `Icor` contains some negative values I'd like to replace with zeros. Whilst this is much asked question, in my case RAM constraints make the task a little bit harder. Take the example:

```
I=rand(6100,6300,72); %# example size of I
[x,y,z]=size(I); %# get the dimensions for later reshaping
I=reshape(I,x*y,z); %# reshape to columns
Icor=function(I) %# apply a function to I, result Icor
Icor(Icor < 0)=0; %# Icor has negatives which need removing
Icor=reshape(Icor,x,y,z); %# reshape back to same size as I (original size)
```

My problem lies in the logical indexing step, `Icor(Icor < 0)=0;`, which is where my RAM maxes out. Is there a creative way around this? (or forgive me if I'm I've missed something really obvious).

Comment: what about clearing the original copy `I` out (clear `I`)? Then, what about extracting subset of `Icor` and working on them one by one?

Comment: Or rewrite `function` to return `0` rather than a negative number, making the step `Icor(Icor < 0)=0` redundant ?

Comment: I've tried clearing the original copy of `I` but it still bugs. Perhaps a loop to remove zeros column-wise on vector of `Icor` then reshape may be the solution

Comment: For the sake of complicating things too much I think I'll just split `I` in half and process each half separately..

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but you can use `I=reshape(I,[],z);` instead of `I=reshape(I,x*y,z);`.

Comment: Looping over columns might be the way to go. I can't even define I on my 32-bit system :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would loop over the last dimension - it is just as efficient as using `vectorized` logical indices. You **must** loop over the last dimension, because the first two are stored contiguously in the memory, and hence such access is the most efficient one:

```
% forgive my lack of memory ;)
I = rand(610,630,72)-0.5;
s = size(I);

% temporary variables for the test
I1 = reshape(I, [], s(3));
I2 = I1;

% method 1
tic;
I1(I1<0) = 0;
toc

% method 2
tic;
for i=1:s(3)
    I2(I2(:,i)<0,i) = 0;
end
toc

isequal(I1, I2)

Elapsed time is 0.321225 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.282395 seconds.

ans =

 1
```

As you see, the loop is actually faster, so it is a win-win situation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start running out of memory, usually you need to change something pretty major to get your memory use back in line.

However, if you want to specifically find the loop equivalent of your mask call, try the code below:

Fully vectorized call (like you have now)

```
Icor(Icor < 0)=0;
```

Per row equivalent (assumed a 2D matrix)

```
for ix = 1:size(Icor,1)
    Icor(Icor(ix,1)<0,  1) = 0;
end
```

Per element equivalent

```
for ix = 1:numel(Icor)
    if iCor(ix) < 0
        iCor(ix) = 0;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for these. I'll have a crack at the per-row equivalent which shouldn't be too memory intensive.